# PCB manufacturer from the 1960's

Tags: pcb

[image: Watermark on pcb]I have an old ferrite memory core plane that has either an "M" or a "W" watermarked on the board and was curious which manufacturer made this board. "Memory 2006000" is stamped on the wire side. "2005900" is stamped on the solder side.There is also hand etched numbers along the edges of the board which include "6401", "M", "1067", "1052" AND "1221"

Does anyone know?

Comment: shape of the logo is usually important ... please add a picture to your post

Comment: Picture please?

Comment: If it appears to be a 'watermark' that's buried in the middle of the layers of the board then it's likely to be that of the manufacturer of the raw 'blank' copper-clad board, rather than the one who turned it into a particular product.

Comment: Definitely the mark of the copper-clad laminate manufacturer, not the PCB maker. And quite possibly long out of business at that. The PCB maker may have placed a logo or other marking on the copper (but often that was not permitted).

Comment: are there any part numbers printed on the board?